# Call class from Web User Control vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, webusercontrol

I got a class name DataAccess

i.e:

```
Public Class DataAccess
-- some functiom--
End class
```

I'm creating one Web User Control file name uc_Data

i can't call DataAccess class from web user control code behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender, ) Handles Me.Load
--want call the class here
End Sub
```

How to do it?

Comment: how are you creating an instance of `DataAccess`?

Comment: i.e :

Public Shared Function CreateCommand() As DbCommand
Dim dbConnectionString As String
Dim dbProvideName as String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution by replace all the class in main project folder instead of put in App_Code folder. Then the class can be call from user control page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a `Shared` function/sub-procedure in the `DataAccess` class, then do this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' Do not need to new up an instance, 
    ' just call method by name prefixed by class name
    DataAccess.DoSomething()
End Sub
```

If you want to call an instance function/sub-procedure in the `DataAccess` class, then do this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' Need to new up an instance of the class and then you can 
    ' call a method from that instance
    Dim theDataAccess As New DataAccess()
    theDataAccess.DoSomething2()
End Sub
```

Comment: my problem is, i can't call DataAccess at all. DataAccess class not in suggested list when i try to write it.

Comment: Is the `DataAccess` class in a separate project (class library)? What namespace is the `DataAccess` class in?

Comment: in the same project, i put in folder Data_Code > Data > DataAccess.vb
The user controls in Controls > uc_Data.asax.vb

Comment: @user2412351 - what namespace is the `DataAccess` class in?